# How to create Restoration Partion?

Tags: partitioning, restore, rescue

For some time now, when buying new computers (laptops in particular) from big name brands-like DELL, HP, TOSHIBA, etc.-most of them come with a "rescue" or "restore" partion instead of installation CD/DVD. Said partitions have everything needed to rebuild the factory installed OS, unfortunately they also include all crapware that the OEM installed on the machine. 
Is it there a way to custom create such a partition with out all the useless software included?. They seem quite appealing considering they only use about 10GB-20GB of space and offer the pretty much the same functionality as a complete system image/backup.

Answer (score 0):

Many tools for Windows PE (Pre-installation environment) can put a similar partition on a CD, USB pendrive, or on your hard drive, however many "recovery partitions" come with OEM-specific software to restore a backup, system image, or the like. To make your own functional recovery partition, you would need to create your own or use an existing backup mechanism to allow your system to be restored via.

If you are a more advanced user, you may be able to fix your system using a small Linux system installed in a partition, or a Windows PE installation by itself, but for the most part, a boot CD will come in more handy for the majority of the time (Fixing a broken MBR, restoring to a new drive after a broken hard drive) as it doesn't rely on the integrity of the same disk you're restoring to.